# Applying Spring web service security in a JAX-WS web service

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have a web application where I have created a sample web service using spring annotation. My web service class looks like:

```
@WebService(serviceName="CalculatorService", endpointInterface="com.abc.xyz.integration.ws.provider.Calculator")
public class CalculatorImpl implements Calculator {

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return a + b;
    }

    @Override
    public int subtract(int a, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return a-b;
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
@WebService
public interface Calculator {

    @WebMethod
    public int add(int a, int b);

    @WebMethod
    public int subtract(int a, int b);
}
```

The web service is deployed correctly on my weblogic server and I am able to call it successfully form a SoapUI client.

Now, I have to add username/password security on it. I read over internet that a good way to do it is by adding a interceptor on your web service path.

Please let me know on how can I add username/password security on my web service.

**EDIT**

I found out that the annotation way of creating a webservice using `@WebService` annotation creates a JAX-WS web service. Now, the question is, How do I apply **spring web service security on my JAX-WS web service**. Is it possible at all or not?

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html)

Comment: @shazin: I have already read spring security doc mentioned by you. But I am still not able to understand on how to apply security on the web service which I have created using annotation method. Is is possible to do it or not?